# Is it possible to "create" properties of objects?

Tags: javascript, object, properties

So, is it possible to create a separate property of an already-existing object?

My example and usage is complicated so I'll provide a simple game example (main game code omitted, i'm not making it lol)

So, instead of doing a variable for a player's exp, i would want a `player.exp` property. I wouldn't want to define the variable as `var exp;` because that would be undefined and I couldnt do `exp+=10;` or similar. I also can't do `var exp=0;` in either the main game loop or the start code. That could mess with other code.

I would want to create an `exp` property for `player` (which is an already-defined object)

So, for example I would want

```
// (start loop) {
    create property exp for player;
    player.exp=0;
}
// (game loop) {
    if(enemyDefeated.name==="soldier") {
        player.exp+=50;
    }
}
```

Is there any function or other way to do this?

Comment: `player.exp = 50` this defines a `exp` property on the object `player`

Comment: have you tried it? does it work?

Comment: What is the problem with this code?

Comment: player.exp = (number) works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`player.exp = value` works, creates a property of the object. Thanks, evolutionxbox!